# why the ethernet and ip header of packets, which are captured by libpcap function, are distorted

Tags: c, linux, libpcap

I used libpcap function pcap_next() to capture some tcp packets from other hosts
I checked the bytes of the captured packets
and notice that
the ethernet and ip header of packets are distorted, in a mess with a lot 0's
but the TCP header is fine

what are potential reasons for this?

codes:

```
pcap_t* create_pcap_handler()
{
    pcap_t *handle;                 /* Session handle */
    char *dev;                      /* The device to sniff on */
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];  /* Error string */
    struct bpf_program fp;          /* The compiled filter */
    char filter_exp[] = "port 32000";  /* The filter expression */
    bpf_u_int32 mask;               /* Our netmask */
    bpf_u_int32 net;                /* Our IP subnet*/

    /* Define the device */
    dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
    if (dev == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't find default device: %s\n", errbuf);
            exit(2);
    }
    /* Find the properties for the device */
    if (pcap_lookupnet(dev, &net, &mask, errbuf) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't get netmask for device %s: %s\n", dev, errbuf);
            net = 0;
            mask = 0;
    }

    struct in_addr tmp;
    tmp.s_addr=net;
    char IPdotdec[20];
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, (void *)&tmp, IPdotdec, 16);
    printf("net is %s\n", IPdotdec);
    tmp.s_addr=mask;
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, (void *)&tmp, IPdotdec, 16);
    printf("mask is %s\n", IPdotdec);
    printf("dev is %s\n",dev);

    handle = pcap_open_live(dev, BUFSIZ, 0, 0, errbuf);
    if (handle == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open device %s: %s\n", dev, errbuf);
            exit(2) ;
    }
    /* Compile and apply the filter */
    if (pcap_compile(handle, &fp, filter_exp, 0, mask) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't parse filter %s: %s\n", filter_exp, pcap_geterr(handle));
            exit(2);
    }
    if (pcap_setfilter(handle, &fp) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't install filter %s: %s\n", filter_exp, pcap_geterr(handle));
            exit(2);
    }

    return handle;
}
```

and the main function

```
int main()
{
    pcap_t * pcap_handler=create_pcap_handler();
    struct pcap_pkthdr pcap_header;      /* The header that pcap gives us */
    const u_char *pcap_packet;           /* The actual packet */
    pcap_packet = pcap_next(pcap_handler, &pcap_header);
    if(pcap_packet !=NULL)
            printf("capture one packet with length of %d\n", pcap_header.len);
    pcap_close(pcap_handler);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this for incoming or outgoing packets ? For outgoing packets, the capture of these layers may be wrong as some of it may be filled in by the network card, AFTER the capture.

Comment: incoming packets, I also used tcpdump to capture the tcp packets, those packets are fine

Comment: Can you provide sample code ?

Comment: I have pasted the codes, thanks!

Comment: You haven't pasted the code to `parse_pkt()`.  Perhaps there's a bug in that code.

Comment: parse_pkt() doesn't matter here, because I mannually checked the packet character string using gdb.

Comment: You should remove code that otherwise just clutters this question. It distracts people that could otherwise provide their help. Make it a minimal example, that can reproduce the error.

Comment: Note that you should only remove code from your question, if you have actually verified, that the error is still reproducible without that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pcap_packet = pcap_next(pcap_handler, &pcap_header);
if(pcap_packet !=NULL)
        printf("capture one packet with length of %d\n", pcap_header.len);
pcap_close(pcap_handler);
parse_pkt(pcap_packet,pcap_header.len);
```

That's not going to work.

When you close `pcap_handler`, there is no guarantee that any pointer returned by a call to `pcap_next()` or `pcap_next_ex()` with `pcap_handler` will continue to be valid.

Try

```
pcap_packet = pcap_next(pcap_handler, &pcap_header);
if(pcap_packet !=NULL)
        printf("capture one packet with length of %d\n", pcap_header.len);
parse_pkt(pcap_packet,pcap_header.len);
pcap_close(pcap_handler);
```

instead.

Comment: I modified the codes according to your advice, now the IP header works fine, but the TCP seq_ack field is wrong!!!!! TCP seq field is OK, what is wrong????

Comment: For incoming packets where the TCP checksum should be valid, do the tcp checksum by yourself and see if it adds up. If you have weird TCP seq acks in packets with a good checksum, then it is your interpretation of the field that is not correct. Also you will be better off using pcap_loop or pcap_dispatch than pcap_next.

Comment: In what sense is the TCP seq_ack field "wrong"?  And what is the code you have that's parsing it?